# How to made enable system extensions on macOS Monterey?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, monterey, drobo

I would like to continue to use my DROBO 5D with the the mac mini 16 GB (M1, 2020) mcOS Monterey.

But it does not pop up on my display, although the older DROBO “4slots” does show up on the screen.
Both are showing up AND work well on my older macBook Pro with the Drobo-Dashboard ( 3.5.2 ), so all data are still available.
But neither of the  2 DROBO’s appears on M1 mac-mini on the Drobo-Dashboard ( 3.6.1 )
Instead this warning sign appears, saying:

“Drobo system extension has been blocked by macOS. Please
dot to “System Preferences >> Security & Privacy >> General”
pane and allow the extension to be loaded.”

Only the older DROBO “4slots” pops up on the screen after a while.
When I am running the Disk utility program also only the older DROBO appears.

When I am doing what is asked in the warning another message appears:

“To enable system extensions, you need to modify your security settings in the Recovery environment.
To do this, shut down your system and hold the Touch ID or power button to launch Startup Security Utility. In Startup Security Utility, enable kernel extensions from the Security Policy button”

If I do so, I am ending up with a message saying:

“Recovery is trying to change system settings.
NO ADMINISTRATOR WAS FOUND”

Now what ?
Thanx for any hints

Comment: Contact the devs and ask for a Monterey compatible version. Is the message you're citing verbatim? Because it talks about both System Extensions and Kernel Extensions. Both are different things. Kernel Extensions are deprecated since macOS 10.15 and almost banned since macOS 11 Big Sur. You can only use them by disabling macOS security measures (which is what they're asking you to do!). A company still asking you to use a Kernel Extension has basically abandoned their product and doesn't want to invest the development time to move to System Extensions.